# Receiving back string of lenght 0 from os.popen('cmd').read()

Tags: python-2.7, automator

I am working with a command line tool called 'ideviceinfo' (see https://github.com/libimobiledevice) to help me to quickly get back serial, IMEI and battery health information from the iOS device I work with daily. It executes much quicker than Apple's own 'cfgutil' tools.

Up to know I have been able to develop a more complicated script than the one shown below in PyCharm (my main IDE) to assign specific values etc to  individual variables and then to use something like to pyclip and pyautogui to help automatically paste these into the fields of the database app we work with. I have also been able to use the simplified version of the script both in Mac OS X terminal and in the python shell without any hiccups.

I am looking to use AppleScript to help make running the script as easy as possible.

When I try to use Applescript's "do shell script 'python script.py'" I just get back a string of lenght zero when I call 'ideviceinfo'. The exact same thing happens when I try to build an Automator app with a 'Run Shell Script' component for "python script.py".

I have tried my best to isolate the problem down. When other more basic commands such as 'date' are called within the script they return valid strings.

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import os

    ideviceinfoOutput = os.popen('ideviceinfo').read()
    print ideviceinfoOutput
    print len (ideviceinfoOutput)

    boringExample = os.popen('date').read()
    print boringExample
    print len (boringExample)
```

I am running Mac OS X 10.11 and am on Python 2.7

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've managed to fix it on my own. I just need to be far more explicit about where the 'ideviceinfo' binary (I hope that's the correct term) was stored on the computer.

Changed one line of code to

```
    ideviceinfoOutput = os.popen('/usr/local/bin/ideviceinfo').read()
```

and all seems to be OK again.